# If the player is left at the set location without being moved, objects won't detect a collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am making my first iOS game and have been making great progress. I have working collision detection however if I run the game and don't move the player from it's set location `player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)`, then the enemies will just go right through the player and won't detect the collision. If I move the player into the enemy from that spot, thats when it starts to work.

I don't know if the issue is in the order I am spawning the player or my collision detection, but this is some code so hopefully you can help.

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None      : UInt32 = 0
    static let All       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Player   : UInt32 = 0b1
    static let Bee: UInt32 = 0b10
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Player != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Enemy != 0)) {
            collision(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, Player: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
    }
}
```

and I'm not sure if you need it, but this is for the player

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
  let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
  player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
  addChild(player)
  physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
  physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
}
```

**EDIT** I forgot this:

```
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width/2)
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
```

Comment: did you set the collision bit mask and contactTestBitMask for the player?

Comment: Check my edit, sorry I forgot to put that code in

Comment: according to your code, you just do contact detection? Collision detection is disabled. did you mean `didBeginContact` is not getting called when you don't move player node?

Comment: can you put a println("contacted") inside didBeginContact and check if its called or not when player has not moved? also in which function did you set the `player.physicsBody` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where in your code is the part of code that you previously forgot to post? The part where you set the collision bit mask and contactTestBitMask for the player?

If collision only works when you move the player, it sound like this part of the code is in the touchesEnded method, is it there?

You may try moving that part of the code to the class init, so it gets executed at the beginning not only when the player is moved.

Comment: It's actually in TouchesBegan. I think you're on to something though :) Where should I move it to?

Comment: to somewhere that doesn't depends on you touching the player for it to get executed..  try just below:
player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)   for the player, and just below wherever you initialize the enemy for the enemies

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! Makes complete sense what a silly mistake

Comment: It happens to all of us sometime! :)